# Rotate an image without using third-party libraries?

Tags: python, image-rotation

I am trying to make a function rotate_image(image, angle) that can rotate an image at a given angle. I do not want to use third-party libraries such as Image Library (PIL) or open-CV. Is it possible? I'm thinking about doing it like that:

```
def rotation(image, angle):
    angle = np.radians(angle)                                                
    Rmat=np.array(( (np.cos(90), -np.sin(90)),
               (np.sin(90),  np.cos(90)) ))
    Inew = np.dot(I,Rmat);
    plt.subplot(1,2,1); plt.imshow(I)
    plt.subplot(1,2,2); plt.imshow(Inew)
```

Comment: How is your image formatted? If it's a numpy array, then sure it's possible. If it's already a PIL data structure, then obviously you need to use PIL. If it's a PNG file, then you can *technically* do it yourself, but it'll be an exercise in frustration parsing the format correctly.

Comment: It's a PNG file. How would you go about it? @SilvioMayolo

Comment: I would use OpenCV. But if you're really insistent on parsing it yourself, reading up on the file format would be a good place to start. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_format

Comment: `numpy` is a third-party library.

Comment: `numpy` is fine to use.

Comment: Yeah you're going to have a fun time trying to write a fully-featured PNG parser for this project. Is there any particular reason for not wanting to use libraries?

Comment: No, I just want to learn.